# Use jq to count elements based on group by

Tags: json, group-by, aggregate, jq

I have a list of movies like this:

```json
[
   {
      "title":"X",
      "genres":[
         {
            "tag":"Horror"
         },
         {
            "tag":"Thriller"
         },
         {
            "tag":"Mystery"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "title":"Zero Dark Thirty",
      "genres":[
         {
            "tag":"Thriller"
         },
         {
            "tag":"Drama"
         },
         {
            "tag":"History"
         },
         {
            "tag":"War"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

I want to query all unique genres and count the number of movies, where the output looks like this:

```json
{
   "Horror":1,
   "Thriller":2,
   "Mystery":1,
   "Drama":1,
   "History":1,
   "War":1
}
```

Is this possible with `jq`?

Edit: I also need to be able to handle movies without genres. These can be ignored. For example:

```json
[
   {
      "title":"Some movie",
      "genres":[
         {
            "tag": null
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "title":"Some other movies",
      "genres":[
         {
            "tag":"Comedy"
         },
         {
            "tag":"Drama"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is.

1. Extract all genres into array
2. Group genres
3. Map to a key-value pair (key = any element of the group, we'll take the first; value = count of elements in the group)
4. Build object from key-value pairs

```
map(.genres[].tag)
| group_by(.)
| map({ key:first, value:length })
| from_entries
```

Output:

```
{
  "Drama": 1,
  "History": 1,
  "Horror": 1,
  "Mystery": 1,
  "Thriller": 2,
  "War": 1
}
```

---

Alternatively, use a `reduce` based approach and simply increase a counter:

```
reduce .[].genres[].tag as $genre ({}; .[$genre] += 1)
```

This is likely more efficient than building an array and grouping.

---

To select only non-null tags, filter through [`values`](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/#arrays-objects-iterables-booleans-numbers-normals-finites-strings-nulls-values-scalars):

```
map(.genres[].tag | values)
| group_by(.)
| map({ key:first, value:length })
| from_entries
```

or

```
reduce (.[].genres[].tag|values) as $genre ({}; .[$genre] += 1)
```

`values` is internally defined as `select(. != null)`.

Comment: [jqplay.org for first solution.](https://jqplay.org/s/CJ7SUxc8dhn)  [jqplay.org for second solution.](https://jqplay.org/s/SgHPFpr_xDK)

Comment: @knittl How would I handle movies without a genres? When `genres` only contain `"tag": null`.

Comment: @Bob I don't know how I would handle them. How should they be handled? You are counting genres, so movies without genre shouldn't affect the genre count

Comment: I get an error `jq: error (at <stdin>:921251): Cannot index object with null` which I assumed is due to a `null` value. I prefer those movies to be ignored.

Comment: @Bob can you edit your question and provide a sample input?

Comment: I've edited my post. Example on jqplay: https://jqplay.org/s/qKHP7fM1Qpl

Comment: @Bob find my updated answer

Answer (score 3):

There is a generic "bag of words" function that makes it easy to solve this task efficiently:

```
def bow(stream): 
  reduce stream as $word ({}; .[($word|tostring)] += 1);
```

With this arrow in your quiver, there are many ways to solve the specific problem at hand.  Here's one that assumes all .tag values are relevant:

```
bow(.. | objects | .tag // empty)
```

Comment: [jqplay.org for solution.](https://jqplay.org/s/GouYwznRd_5)